# JSF2 and Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, architecture, spring-aop

We are using JSF2.0.2 Managed bean(faces-config) framework in weblogic2 ,for exception handling we couldn't use JSF2 framework as it has bug to get the exact exception stack trace.

So thought of using Spring AOP ,which will give control of catching exception after calling the Backing Bean methods.

To do that ,should i need to first do Spring-JSF integration? is there any other alternatives??

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You can use real AspectJ for that, so you do not need Spring.